# Need help replace multiple string with similar pattern (using notepad++ ver.7)

Tags: xml, notepad++

so i have around 1000+ lines in notepad++ ver.7 (XML file) , in each line there's a string that contain this percific pattern

```
items="number,number,number"
```

and i need to replace that pattern with

```
items="0,0,0"
```

the number varies between lines

(sorry bout my broken english and im very new to notepad , actually this is my 1st time using it , learning XML coding and this is kinda like a homework)

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bitems="\K\d+,\d+,\d+(?=")`
- Replace with: `0,0,0`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
items="         # literally
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\d+,\d+,\d+     # 3 numbers comma separated
(?=")           # positive lookahead, make sure we have quote after
```

**Given:**

```
items="123,456,789"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
items="0,0,0"
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]